# Any temporary fix for / being remounted as read-only?

Tags: linux, mount, hard-disk, readonly

My disk has a few bad sectors and has already failed the SMART tests. It obviously is going down. 
It gets remounted to read only and I have to fsck and reboot all over again. Is it safe for me to remove the `errors=remount-ro` part from the fstab file?

Comment: Did you consider keeping the file system in `ro` state, connect you backup device, synchronize and dispose the failing drive?

Comment: I am getting a new hard disk installed this weekend.It's long time from now and rebooting every now and then is really frustrating. Wanted to know if this could 'calm' things down till I replace the drive. Yeah I did backup my data. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick note: I assume when you say its "failed the SMART tests", you mean that it has one or more pre-fail attributes failing now. Not that a long self-test failed. If its just back blocks, then you just need to get them remapped, and your problem is solved—even without a new disk. (But still have backups!)

Is it safe? Well, define safe... I mean, you're continuing to use a disk that (via SMART failure) is telling you it expects severe data loss within the next day.

`errors=remount-ro` is intended to prevent potential bad outcomes of attempting to continue full use of a corrupted filesystem:

- You could get kernel panics. Relatively safe (well, you may lose work in progress when the system panics).
- You could get massive filesystem corruption. This is the real big one; you could lose a *lot* of files when e.g., the kernel loses track of the inode backing `/home`. Or when you get two files "sharing" the same sectors. Fsck should "fix" this regardless, but you may wind up with a good part of your filesystem sitting around in lost+found, and many of the files corrupted from overlapping sectors.

I hope you already have a backup. I hope you've tested that backup.

Answer (score 0):

When my root HDD get damaged, the indicator just kept blinking, and the system stuck,

A temporary solution is try to fill the damaged cell blocks, first find all bad blocks with `badblocks`, then use `hdparm` to tell the HDD stop using that block.

But that would cost a great time, I don't it worth it.

Comment: Well, this is the rare case when I accept using DOS or Windows. ;-) Sector-level operations like these are ideally done with `Victoria` and other tools, lots of which are available on common boot-CDs like *Hiren's Boot CD* and others. Yet another inside tip: `Victoria` sometimes FAILS when a HDD was locked by ATA password, and keeps complaining it cannot access the drive. I could solve this by aid of its derivative, `MHDD`, which (make sure to use `DisPWD` option, not "Unlock"!) could remove the password *permanently* and made the drive available and readable for *any* tool.